# Installing PySCIPOpt on OS X

Tags: python, scip

I am trying to install PySCIPOpt on my mac, following the instructions [here](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/112). When I try to test it as follows:

```
from pyscipopt import Model
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- packages/pyscipopt/scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SCIPnlpiComp
```

I tried following the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/112#issuecomment-415686644), but the error still occurs. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This very much sounds like a version inconsistency. Please make sure that you are always using the [latest version of the SCIP Optimization Suite](https://scip.zib.de/index.php#download) together with the current PySCIPOpt version. You can check which version is linked by inspecting the `scip.so` library mentioned in the question:

```
otool -L scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Comment: I definitely used the 6.0.1 installer, and I just ran `pip install pyscipopt` once I set the SCIPOPTDIR. When I run that command, I get `scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)`. Is this right?

Comment: This can't be the full error message. Could you please share the entire message?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SCIPnlpiComp
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so`

Comment: OK, but did you check your environment variables? there might be an old SCIP in some `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or something similar.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything like `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my environment variables.

Comment: OK, so what does ´otool -L´ report on the library?

Comment: `scip.cpython-37m-darwin.so: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)`

Comment: I'm sorry but this makes no sense to me. There should be more libraries. Maybe it's a different option with `otool`?